# 2 cmd windows flash after boot

Tags: command-line, cmd.exe, onedrive

For some reasons after the boot 2 cmd windows popped up and closed very quickly. I've managed to take a screenshot
[image]

As you can see it's prompting for some access denied error regarding OneDrive even though I don't use OneDrive. Is there any way to figure out the reason for this behavior?

Comment: what OS are you using? have you done anything your self to fix this issue?

Comment: I'm on Win10. Nope I'm still trying to research into this

Comment: from what i can gather the dll's its trying to run are onedrive dll are you able to re-apply privileges to those files?

Comment: Nope I didn't try yet. Not sure if I even need to. As you can see from the screenshot the OneDrive folder is called 17.3.6301.0127. But I have also found a new folder 17.3.6390.0509 with a new version number created at the exact same timemark this error occured
It could be something to do with version upgrade or something

Comment: interesting, i would try re-applying security settings and allowing your self full control over that folder and running one drive after.(one drive seems to come with windows 10 by default)

Comment: It didn't occur after the second reboot. So I'm guessing it's fixed for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use the version Microsoft Office that comes with "OneDrive" like Office 2013 or newer?
Well in that case you can disable "OneDrive" from startup programs.
To do that on windows 8 and newer(or 10)[1]Open Task Manager > Select "Show more details" then on the navigate to startup tab. And select OneDrive and you can disable it if you want. Well this will not disable "Onedrive" but it can solve this issue.

(1)Note: On windows 7 and older you will need an third party program.

Comment: I do not use Office at all I'm afraid

Comment: Well i edited the answer but i think that will not help. Which version of windows you use.

Comment: I'm using windows 10

Comment: Windows 10. Well search for OneDrive from the search menu

Comment: It's there and it's working if this is what you want me to check. It asks for my e-mail to begin its work but like I said I don't use it

Comment: Well I checked my computer that i have two OneDrive folders too.

Comment: Just try to go to windows marketspace find Onedrive Edit: It doesnt work.

Comment: What are the version numbers of your OneDrive folders?

Comment: 17.3.6386.0412 and 17.3.6390.0509

Comment: Oh as I mentioned you can do the solution thats on my first answer. Even if you dont have office. That will not unistall it but it will not pop-out at every reboot or boot

Comment: Interesting. I think we're onto something here. In the older folder there is only 3 files in my case. FileSyncShell64.dll, msvcr120.dll and msvcp120.dll. In the new folder there is a ton of folders. What about you?
edit: I will try it on my next reboot thanks